# Java - Access Nested JSONArray values dynamically

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file (`myjsonfile.json`) which stores the folder structure along with file contents as a JSON. It is as follows:

```
{
  "name":"folder1",
  "type":"directory",

  "children":[
    {"name":"info",
      "type":"directory",
      "children": [
        {
        "name":"info1.txt",
        "type":"file",
        "content": ["abcd", "efgh", "ijk"]
        }]
    },
    {"name":"data",
     "type":"directory",
     "children": [{
          "name":"data1.txt",
          "type":"file",
          "content": ["abcd", "xyz"]
        }]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is access the `content` of either of the two text files (`info1.txt` or `data1.txt`) dynamically and store them as a List of Strings. By  dynamically I mean that the filename i.e., the key (`info1.txt` or `data1.txt`) will be provided by the user.

I was able to parse and get the value in a static way by using `org.json` library like this:

```
         File file = new File(myfilepath/myjsonfile.json);
         String jsonContent = null;
         try {
             content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         // Convert JSON string to JSONObject
         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonContent);
         JSONArray children =  jsonObj.getJSONArray("children");
         System.out.println(children.toString());
         JSONObject  child0 = children.getJSONObject(0);
         System.out.println(child0.toString());
         // and so on...
```

However, I can't figure out how to make this dynamic and store the file contents as a List of Strings based on the user input of the filename.

Can someone please help me out?

EDIT: Clarified the question. `myfilepath` here refers to the file path of the JSON file (`myjsonfile.json`).

Comment: can you more explain what do you need, I dont understand

Comment: Suppose a user says that "I want the contents of  the file called `info1.txt` as a List of Strings". The filename is dynamically chosen by the user i.e., it can be `data1.txt` instead of `info1.txt` also. Whatever the file name is (`info1.txt` or `data1.txt`), the contents of the file should be stored as a List of Strings. I hope I could clarify it properly.

Comment: @rbh-93 you are already using a variable `myfilepath` for the filename.  This is where `info1.txt` should go...

Comment: @aarbor, `myfilepath` is where the JSON file is located. I don't have `info1.txt` on my local machine. The contents of `info1.txt` are there in the JSON file only.

Comment: @aarbor, maybe there is some misunderstanding. Let me generalise a bit more. My objective is to retrieve the value of a key(`content`) based on the user input `info1.txt` or `data1.txt` dynamically and store these contents as a list of strings. It's not really about whether or not the user will upload the file. That is quite irrelevant as I only have this JSON file and nothing else.

Comment: @rbh-93 i understand now - added solution.  You need to loop through the objects and pull out the array you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own `tree-node-walker`:

```
class NodeWalker {

    private final JSONObject object;

    public NodeWalker(JSONObject object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public List<String> findContentFor(String name) {
        LinkedList<JSONObject> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(object);
        while (queue.size() > 0) {
            JSONObject next = queue.pop();
            Object fileName = next.get("name");
            final String contentName = "content";
            if (fileName != null && fileName.equals(name) && next.has(contentName)) {
                JSONArray content = next.getJSONArray(contentName);
                if (content == null) {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                IntStream.range(0, content.length()).forEach(i -> result.add(content.getString(i)));
                return result;
            }
            final String childrenName = "children";
            if (next.has(childrenName)) {
                JSONArray array = next.getJSONArray(childrenName);
                IntStream.range(0, array.length()).forEach(i -> queue.add(array.getJSONObject(i)));
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ProfileApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(jsonFile.toPath());
        String json = String.join("", strings);

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        NodeWalker nodeWalker = new NodeWalker(jsonObj);
        String[] files = {"info1.txt", "data1.txt", "data2.txt"};
        for (String file : files) {
            System.out.println(file + " contents -> " + nodeWalker.findContentFor(file));
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
info1.txt contents -> [abcd, efgh, ijk]
data1.txt contents -> [abcd, xyz]
data2.txt contents -> []
```

### Gson

Much easier to use [`Gson`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5) library and class model of your `JSON` payload. Let's create a class:

```
class FileNode {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<FileNode> children;
    private List<String> content;

    public List<String> findContent(String name) {
        LinkedList<FileNode> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(this);
        while (queue.size() > 0) {
            FileNode next = queue.pop();
            if (next.name.equals(name)) {
                return next.content;
            }
            if (next.children != null) {
                queue.addAll(next.children);
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<FileNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<FileNode> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public List<String> getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(List<String> content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FileNode{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", children=" + children +
                ", content=" + content +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Which we can use as below:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

        FileNode root = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(jsonFile), FileNode.class);
        String[] files = {"info1.txt", "data1.txt", "data2.txt"};
        for (String file : files) {
            System.out.println(file + " contents -> " + root.findContent(file));
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
info1.txt contents -> [abcd, efgh, ijk]
data1.txt contents -> [abcd, xyz]
data2.txt contents -> []
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. GSON is also another way but that is only when the JSON contents are static. In my case however, the JSON fie can change. As you might have already guessed, the JSON is generated by another application which recursively parses a folder structure to JSON based on what folder path is given.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each object and see if `name` has the file you are looking for.  I would recommend you use a more verbose JSON processing library such as Jackson or Gson to make things easier.  However, given your current implementation, you want to do something along the lines of:

```
        if(jsonObj.has("children")) {
            JSONArray mainChild = jsonObj.getJSONArray("children");
            for(int i=0; i < mainChild.length(); i++) {
                if(((JSONObject)mainChild.get(i)).has("children")) {
                    JSONArray child = ((JSONObject)mainChild.get(i)).getJSONArray("children");
                    for(int j=0; j < child.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject obj = child.getJSONObject(j);
                        if(obj.has("name") 
                                && fileNameToLookFor.equals(obj.getString("name"))) {
                            if(obj.has("content")) {
                                return obj.getJSONArray("content");
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: This is also fine. Just a minor thing `ob.getJSONArray("children");` should be `jsonObj.getJSONArray("children");` I think?